# I want to use Python as a scripting language for my game, can I use it purely with C (not C++)?

Tags: python, c

I want to use Python as a scripting language for my game, can I use it purely with C (not C++)?  It is important to me that I not use C++, and purely use C instead.

Comment: Please do some cursory research before asking questions.

Comment: I agree with @Joe Wreschnig but i dont agree on the downvote: 0 is worse than -1 (it attracts less attention) and there are chances that someone gives smart answers to dumb questions.

Comment: @FxIII a chance of getting a smart answer is not a reason to keep a bad question, otherwise you wouldn't close anything and it would be all a mess.

Comment: @Lo'oris: Indeed, is just a matter to compare the cost of the "mess" to the value of the answers. While this is can't be done a priori I suggest to give to dumb questions the time attract smart ansers, then evaluate, then close (or remove) :)

Comment: @Fxlll (Can't tell if your name is i or l) The idea of downvotes is to show that a question is either poorly worded, vague, off topic, or in this case, just not researched at all.

Comment: It's amazing how much people will spend energy telling someone they are wrong, have asked a dumb question, or that they haven't done any research.  How simple it is to just answer the question instead, offer a little advice that takes you a minute to create, and move on.  Let's make people feel welcome here, not that it's a bunch of moderator nazis flaunting their high scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the official Python website/documentation suggest, "yes" you can embed Python purely with C.

- http://docs.python.org/c-api/
- http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html

Answer (score 3):

I know that is not strictly related to your question (for which the answer is simply yes) but you should consider to **extend** Python with your C function or to use **another language for scripting**, *Lua* perhaps.

You can try the first option by compiling your C functions as dynamic library and then use **ctypes**. This gives you the chance to have a **working prototype in almost no time**.

If you profiled your C app before, you can profile the protype too, comparing the two to evaluate the ctypes overhead; **ctypes** (*Foreign Function Interface* in general) **is not embedding** but you have chances to see that this is **suitable for you with little or no modification**